# Excel is performing StrToMember MDX queries before the main query which is taking 45 minutes to refresh a cube

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I have a slow pivot table connected to SSAS.
When I run the query, it takes 45 minutes to refresh.
I can see in the Profiler that it is running the following queries multiple times which is where all the time is spent. It then makes a final query with the results of this query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Product].[Style].[XL_PT0] AS 'strtomember("[Product].[Style].&[BA13W4406P]").UniqueName' MEMBER [Product].[Style].[XL_PT1] AS 'strtomember("[Product].[Style].&[BA13W4393W]").UniqueName'
```

Why is Excel doing this? Is there a problem with the setup of my cube whereby Excel doesn't know some information about the member so it is doing a further query to find out more information before performing the final query?

I've copied the user's pivot table into a fresh workbook and upon refreshing, I still get the behaviour. The other weird thing is that if I remove the filter on Product.Style (use the all member and remove it all together), I still see these queries in the profiler?!

[image]

Comment: Do you have a slicer or filter on product style? Can you try clearing that filter and see if that's the culprit? I think it's checking whether the filtered members still exist and what they are named but want to be sure.

Comment: There's no slicer but there is a filter on product. Even if it is the culprit (which I suspect it is), I only seems to do it when using a specific measure. I'm going to spend more time on it tomorrow. I thought setting `MemberNamesUnique` to True might have an impact but there's not alot of information around as to what impacts this property has.

Comment: can you describe the filter? Is it correct that the style field is in the PivotTable filters section (rather than on rows) and is is correct that you have filtered to hundreds or thousands of members?

Comment: also I'm surprised it takes 45 minutes. Are you testing over a slow VPN connection or something? About how many of those queries does it run?

Comment: No, not over a VPN- local network. I would say hundreds. It is running one for every 128 products and then once it has run all those queries, it runs the main query which has a list of every product. Each query takes roughly 3-4 seconds to run.There is certainly a lot of members selected (I calculated probably about 12,000). The user generally selects the All member and then deselects a few products. I'm not sure why other's aren't seeing this issue and why it only seems to happen when using our stock measure (which is by far the biggest...about 500 thousand records per day).

Comment: @GregGalloway- see my update with a screenshot of the Profiler and my update about how removing the Product.Style filter still runs these in the background.

Comment: very strange. I can't reproduce that. When I remove the filter then those queries go away. Let's focus on the 3 seconds for each query. What version of Analysis Services? Multidimensional or Tabular? If you connect Object Explorer in SSMS the it will show the exact version number in the top server node. If you restart the SSAS service can you reproduce the behavior? (Occasionally we have seen memory fragmentation issues where slowness gets worse and worse until the service is restarted)

Comment: Ok so I've found that the queries are run when you refresh a pivot that has the dimension on as a filter but has some members deselected. I checked our legacy data warehouse and it doesnt the same thing except the same query takes 42ms, whereas our new cube (we are replacing the old one) takes almost 4 seconds. There are more members but wouldn't have thought it would make that big of a difference. I'll restart the service and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: by my calc at 42ms that would be about 2 minutes instead of 45 minutes. Still slow but much better and more what I would expect. I would also look at possible hardware issues. For example we spin up a new server and the network drivers were out-of-date resulting in huge latency on every query. After that was resolved it was as snappy as the old server.

Comment: the other obvious solution is to identify the styles users remove via filter. Then add a new dimension attribute to that Product dimension something like ExcludedStyleFlag=Yes/No. Use that in your PivotTable filter.

Comment: Yes I did think of that however various users will have various uses. These servers are both identical as they are virtual machines, with the same specifications. I've performed a reset on the server with no change. I've also emptied the dimension and run the query and it still takes 3 seconds, so I don't think the extra members in the query are the issue. I'm going to deploy my project to the old server and see if it is any quicker. Certainly a weird one. The performance of the cube is quite good- it just seems to be this specific use case.

Comment: what is the exact version number on the old and new server. I would definitely install the latest cumulative update on the new server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124284/discussion-between-lock-and-greggalloway).

Comment: I've just had a colleage run the same query who is using Excel 2013 and it doesn't run those `WITH MEMBER` statements at all.... it refreshes instantly. I'm going to get my version upgraded and see if that helps.

Comment: from the chat you are running SQL 2012 SP2. I looked at SP3 and subsequent cumulative updates and didn't spot a fix that looked like the culprit for 3 second queries. But it's still worth testing an upgrade to SP3. On the Excel side I'm glad Excel 2013 seems to solve it!!

Comment: @GregGalloway- see my answer. Removing a default member from one of my attributes made all the difference. Are these really that bad for performance?!

Comment: great catch. Where did you set the default member? An ALTER statement or the dimension attribute DefaultMember property? Was it on another attribute in the Product dimension? This surprises me!

Comment: We have a boolean attribute that is called "is reported" which only about 5 products have a false. It's so we don't report products like freight etc in our sales. This was set against the DefaultMemver property against the attribute in the product dimension, not through the script. I can get around this by creating a new dimension for just this attribute (and this tested fine) however I'm still a bit curious why the speed is so bad using a default member. Any ideas? Thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: I added a comment and a link with some info to review about the cube initialization sequence to your other thread. I'm not sure what's going on for sure. But see if that helps. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39739236/5070440

Answer (score 1):

I found that removing a default member that I had set on one of my attributes of the Product dimension made all the difference.