# Slow dimension because it had a default member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an SSAS cube that has a dimension with about 500,000 members.
Performance is surprisingly good until I had a default member on one of the attributes (a boolean Yes/No value that we default to Yes).

This change makes a refresh go from 5 seconds to over 20 minutes.

Are default values known to be bad for performance? I can't really see anything on Google suggesting that they are bad performers.

For context, when refreshing a PivotTable, Excel was executing a heap of `WITH MEMBER` statements, with each taking about 3.5 seconds. Removing the default member brought that down to 40ms.

Comment: You might review this article and see if it helps you understand what's going on. Typically the cube initialization is cached after a user connects for the first time after processing. But maybe you are hitting some edge case that prevents that caching from happening? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/12/31/default-members-mdx-scripts-security-kpis-and-perspectives.aspx